# Reading/listening Quran in another language

Tags: quran-recitation, language, reading-quran

My question is regarding the recitation and listening of the Quran and it's benefits:

I have searched myself of course, but I did not find an answer to my question so far so insha-Allah I will get it here.

So far I understand that reciting the `Quran` is the only way for it to be an intercessor based on the following Hadiths:

> Abu Umama said he heard Allah's Messenger (may peace be upon him) say:
>   Recite the Qur'an, for on the Day of Resurrection it will come as an intercessor for those who recite It.
>
> اقْرَءُوا الْقُرْآنَ فَإِنَّهُ يَأْتِي يَوْمَ الْقِيَامَةِ شَفِيعًا لأَصْحَابِهِ
>
> [[Sahih Muslim]](http://sunnah.com/muslim/6/302)

#### Al-Tirmidhi Hadith 1963        Narrated by Abdullah ibn Amr

> Allah's Messenger (saws) said, "Fasting and the Qur'an will intercede
>   for man (on the Day of Judgment). Fasting says, 'O my Lord, I have
>   kept him away from his food and his passions by day, so accept my
>   intercession for him.' The Qur'an says, 'I have kept him away from
>   sleep by night, so accept my intercession for him.' Then their
>   intercession is accepted."

In another famous narration the Messenger of Allah (saws) has declared ‘(On the Day of Judgment) the Quran will be a ‘hujja’ (argument) either for you or against you!’

I do not know *Arabic* and insha-Allah one day I will be able to read it if Allah wills but for now I read it in English (or in *Arabic* but with western alphabet but of course I do not understand it) so I read it in language I understand, because I want to understand what I read. Does this count as reciting (as it would if I would read it in Arabic) then even if it is in another language?

I thank you for your time for reading my question and the time to answer it. May Allah guide and help you through any hardship he has chosen for you and insha-Allah grant you the eternal life in paradise my brother.

#### Al-Tirmidhi Hadith 218         Narrated by Anas ibn Malik

> Allah's Messenger (saws) said: ‘The seeking of knowledge is obligatory
>   for every Muslim.’

Comment: Salaams and welcome to Islam Stack Exchange.  This is a very good post, but I feel it would be stronger if it was edited and posted as two separate questions.

Comment: See also these two related questions: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2002/reading-vs-listening-to-the-quran-during-ramadan?rq=1 http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/406/reading-of-quran-in-a-language-other-than-arabic?rq=1

Comment: It would be very good initiative for your to make the efforts and learn arabic as it makes a big difference in really understanding Quran. For now, you can read, recite and listen to it in any language you wish, with absolutely no problem.

Comment: I second rowman - Allah chose to send his message in Arabic for a reason, because this is his choosen language. He didn't choose turk or belgium languages because they are lesser languages not able to handle his message, therefor any attempt by man to translate will mean lots of the message is lost.

Comment: @goldPseudo I think this question is really a duplicate of those two.

Answer (score 3):

As The Prophet Shallallahu 'alaihi wasallam like to hear the Quran, so should we.

> Ibn Mas'ud (Radiyallahu 'anhu) reported: The Prophet (Shallallahu
>   'alaihi wasallam) said to me, *'Recite the Qur’an to me.'* I said, 'Ya
>   Rasoolallah! Shall I recite it to you when it was revealed to you?' He
>   (Shallallahu 'alaihi wasallam) said, ***'I like to hear it from
>   others.'*** Then I began to recite Surah an-Nisa. When I reached the
>   ayah:
>
> > فَكَيْفَ إِذَا جِئْنَا مِن كُلِّ أُمَّةٍ بِشَهِيدٍ وَجِئْنَا بِكَ
> >     عَلَىٰ هَـٰؤُلَاءِ شَهِيدًا
> >
> > So how [will it be] when We bring from every nation a witness and we
> >     bring you, [O Muhammad] against these [people] as a witness? (QS. An-Nisa' 4: 41)
>
> (Having heard it) he (Shallallahu 'alaihi wasallam) said, *'Enough!
>   Enough!'* When I looked at him, I found his eyes were overflowing with
>   tears. (al-Bukhari and Muslim)

[Source: Reciting the Quran beautifully](http://forums.islamicawakening.com/f43/reciting-the-quran-beautifully-20978/)

And we are ordered to listen to Al-Quran when someone (or recording) recite it.

> وَإِذَا قُرِئَ الْقُرْآنُ فَاسْتَمِعُوا لَهُ وَأَنصِتُوا لَعَلَّكُمْ
>   تُرْحَمُونَ
>
> "So when the Qur'an is recited, then listen to it and pay attention
>   that you may receive mercy." (QS. Al-A'raf 7: 204)

And reciting Al-Quran in the pleasant tone with proper *makhorijul huruf* and *tajweed* will be what you want next, just as someone who has listened to a great poetry, then he will have the desire to recite it too. Because Al-Quran is the most beautiful poetry, better than any song and music.

*Allahu a'lam bi-s sawab*

Answer (score 0):

**Answer to question 1**

Surely, the one reciting the `Quran` will get the more benefit in terms of *Amal*, but even listening to it is a kind of *ibadat*, and Allah will grant with greater *Amal* too.

At-least listening to `Quran` is better that any other worldy work that you might be doing. So, keeping oneself engaged with some kind of *ibadat* is also a good thing, as you are also keeping yourself away from sin activities, which you might do if not even listening to `Quran`.

Answer (score 0):

Readers of the Quran shaded with umbrellas grace, surrounded by angels and God revealed to him calmness and alertness. Mentioned in the hadith narrated by Abu Hurayrah anhu, said the Prophet sallallaahu 'alaihi wasallam which means:

> "There is a gathering of people in the house than the houses of Allah
>   (mosques) who read the Qur'an and mutual learning between them but
>   they were relegated to the peace, mercy clothed, surrounded by the
>   angels and God's grace in remembrance of those who in side.

Readers of the Qur'an has given his heart to the light by Allah Subhanahu wa Ta'ala and maintaining of darkness. Narrated than Abu Hurayrah anhu which means:

> "That Rasulullah sallallaahu 'alaihi wasallam said:" Anybody who heard
>   one ayah Allah Ta'ala than the Book (the Qur'an) was written for him
>   a double kindness. Anybody who reads it anyway, is the light of on qiyamat day

In Quran sura Fushshilat (41): 44

> And if we make it a reading Quran in a language other than Arabic,
>   they would have said: "Why are not its verses explained?" If (worth Al
>   Quran) in a foreign language are (Rasulullah SAW are) Arabian ? ..

So you'd better to read Qur'an in Arabic for the kindness that you can be much different. Reading the Quran is right will thrill your heart.
Wallahu a'lam ..
Learn Quran continues .. may Allah Ta'ala bless you

Answer (score 0):

Surah Ar-Rum, Ch. No. 30, V. No. 22, that... And amongst His signs, is the creation of the heavens and the earth, and the variation in your languages, and your colors. Verily in that, is a sign for those who know’.

Asalamaleykum It shouldn't matter which language you read the Glorious Quran in brother Allah (SWT) created all languages.  What matters is you embrace it without questioning it and ask Allah (SWT) to make you understand what you are reading or hearing. 
 The Prophet Muhammed (PBUH) could not read or write he was taught the Quran verbally by the Angel Jibrail (may Allah be pleased with him) in Arabic because that was his language and so he could get his message spread to his people in a language they would understand.

“And thus We have inspired unto you (O Muhammad) an Arabic Qur’ân that you may warn the mother of the towns (Makkah) and all around it” (Soorah ash-Shura: 7)

The way the Prophet (PBUH) taught Islam was verbally and through his actions.  A lot of early Muslims at the time of the Prophet (PBUH) could not read or write but they heard it the Quran being recited and embraced Islam.  Allah (SWT) sent the Quran in their Mother language so they could understand it either way, the Quran was sent in an Arabic language but its message Islam is for any race.  I am not a scholar or shaykh I'm  just a Muslim brother and i hope this helps this is my opinion and of course Allah (SWT) knows best and always remember he is the most Gracious most Merciful. Ameen.

“And truly this (the Qur’ân) is a revelation from the Lord of the 'Alamin (mankind, jinns and all that exists), which the trustworthy Ruh (Jibreel) has brought down upon your heart (O Muhammad) that you may be (one) of the warners, in the plain Arabic language” (Soorah ash-Shura: 192-195)