# Does reciting fatiah and gifting rewards to the dead actually help them?

Tags: hadith, practical-islam, death, reward

Does reciting [Surah Fatiha](http://quran.com/1) once and [Surah Tauheed](http://quran.com/112) three times and after that gifting thawab to dead people, actually help the dead in hereafter?

**I want to know the hadiths in favour of this custom.**

*Note: Both Shia and Sunni views are welcome.*

Comment: Helpful article [Things that Benefit the Dead](http://sunnahonline.com/library/beliefs-and-methodology/83-things-that-benefit-the-dead).

Answer (score 3):

Yes why not, Doesn't your dua's for their well being or asking Allah for sending them to jannah will not be listen. Or you need any reference for that. Okay here are few references for your question.

The Holy Qur'an has stressed upon Muslims to pray for the welfare of other Muslims as brothers and well wishers in the Islamic fraternity; funeral prayer of deceased Muslim is a glaring example in this behalf.

In the Mishkaat, Babul Fitan, Babul Malaahim, Chapter Two, there is a saying of Hadrat Abu Huraira:

> يضمن لي منكم أن أصلي في مسجد العشاء ، يعني بالأيلة ركعتين أو أربعة ، يقول هذه عن أبي هريرة

Is there any of you who will undertake to pray two or four rak'ahs on my behalf in the mosque of al-Ashshar, stating, "they are on behalf of Abu Hurayrah"

Sunan Abi Dawood, Kitab al-Malaahim, Vol 2, Page 244, Hadith 3754
Shau'ab al-Iman lil Bayhaqi, Bab al Fadail al-Hajj wa al-Umrah, Vol. 9, Page 152, Hadith 3960

From the above narration three clear problems and their solutions can be deduced namely:

To offer physical act of worship (Namaz) with the intention of conveying the thawab of that Namaz to any other person is permissible.
To utter by the tongue praying Almighty Allah to convey the thawab to so and so (by Name) is much better than simple intention.
To offer the Namaz in the Masjid of some righteous saintly person with the intention of receiving more thawab is also permissible.

> Hadith # 1

Narrated 'Aisha:

> Allah's Apostle said, "Whoever died and he ought to have fasted (the missed days of Ramadan) then his guardians must fast on his behalf."

[Sahih Bukhari Book 31 Hadith 173]

Hadith # 2

> في ذكر البصرة الملاحم سنن أبي داود
>   ‏ ‏حدثنا ‏ ‏محمد بن المثنى ‏ ‏حدثني ‏ ‏إبراهيم بن صالح بن درهم ‏ ‏قال سمعت ‏ ‏أبي ‏ ‏يقول ‏
>   ‏انطلقنا حاجين فإذا رجل فقال لنا إلى جنبكم قرية يقال لها ‏ ‏الأبلة ‏ ‏قلنا نعم قال من يضمن لي منكم أن يصلي لي في ‏‏ مسجد العشار ‏‏ ركعتين أو أربعا ويقول هذه ‏ ‏لأبي هريرة ‏ ‏سمعت خليلي رسول الله ‏‏ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏ ‏يقول ‏ ‏إن الله يبعث من ‏‏ مسجد العشار ‏ ‏يوم القيامة شهداء لا يقوم مع شهداء ‏ ‏بدر ‏ ‏غيرهم ‏
>   ‏قال ‏ ‏أبو داود ‏ ‏هذا المسجد مما ‏ ‏يلي ‏
>   ,
>
> The sahabi, Abu Hurayra, urged some people to pray 2 raka’ahs in Masjid Ashaar and told them to say after the prayers, “Haaza li Abi Hurayra”. THIS IS FOR ABU HURAYRA (Abu Dawud vol 2 p236)

Hadith # 3

Narrated Abdullah ibn Amr ibn al-'As:

> Al-'As ibn Wa'il left his will that a hundred slaves should be emancipated on his behalf. His son Hisham emancipated fifty slaves and his son Amr intended to emancipate the remaining fifty on his behalf, but he said: I should ask first the Apostle of Allah (peace_be_upon_him). He, therefore, came to the Prophet (peace_be_upon_him) and said: Apostle of Allah, my father left in his will that a hundred slaves should be emancipated on his behalf and Hisham has emancipated fifty on his behalf and fifty remain. Shall I emancipate them on his behalf? The Apostle of Allah (peace_be_upon_him) said: Had he been a Muslim and you had emancipated slaves on his behalf, or given sadaqah on his behalf, or performed the pilgrimage, that would have reached him. 
>   ,
>   [Abu Dawud Book 17 Hadith 2877 ]

Hadith # 4

> Abdullah b. Buraida (Allah be pleased with him) reported on the authority of his father: When we were sitting with the Messenger of Allah (may peace be upon him), a woman came to him and said: I had gifted to my mother a maid-servant, and now she (the mother) has died. Thereupon he (the Holy Prophet) said: There is a definite reward for you and she (the maid-servant) has been returned to you as an inheritance. She (that woman) again said: Fasts of a month (of Ramadan) are due upon her; should I observe them on her behalf?He (the Holy Prophet) said: Observe fasts on her behalf. She (again) said: She did not perform Hajj, should I perform it on her behalf? He (the Holy Prophet) said: Perform Hajj on her behalf.

[Sahih Muslim Book 6 Hadith 2558]
Hadith # 5

> Jabir b. 'Abdullah (Allah be pleased with him) reported: We performed Hajj along with Allah's Messenger (may peace be upon him), and we sacrificed a camel on behalf of seven persons, and a cow on behalf of seven persons.

[Sahih Muslim Book 7 Hadith 3026 ]

Links for further references

https://radianceofislam.wordpress.com/2013/12/15/understanding-fatiha-proven-virtues-and-practise/

http://www.alahazrat.net/islam/permissibility-of-fatiha-teeja-daswan-and-chaliswan.php

Allah & his Messenger Knows Best

May Allah guide us on straits path.

Comment: Your answer seems to me contrary to what we deduce from the hadith mentioned by 'servant of Wiser', unless you take in account that hadith, before building a principle.

Comment: @WailingNightingale, I'm actually not a Muhaddith, It can also be reversed that the hadith which is mention by 'servant of Wisher' is contrary to what Hadiths I took from the sahi muslim,but still if you read the Hadith mentioned by 'servant-of-wisher', In that Messenger of Allah Peace be Upon Him clearly saying that Among the three things  righteous offspring who pray for him will be given to the person who dies.

Comment: About the ahadith quoted few things need to be understood beforehand. Hadith#1 and #4 talks of obligatory deeds which he missed to perform, not the optional deeds. #2 at the first sight seems conflicting in nature, as performing a deed on the behalf of a living person is illogical, and its authenticity needs to be verified before it can be used as a support. #3 like #1 is more about fulfilling a deceased person's will, than anything else. #5 is specifically about the legality of sharing a sacrificial animal between people,

Comment: @servant-of-Wiser there is nothing to feel sorry :). Thank you for the edit. I also wanted to point to fact that even if the ahadith quoted in support of the argument and the like of it are authentic and guaranteeing the delivery of rewards to the deceased, it would in no way validate the specific manner of doing it, like what is suggested in the question. Thank you again.

Comment: http://www.alahazrat.net/islam/permissibility-of-fatiha-teeja-daswan-and-chaliswan.php

Comment: Don't consider things by applying your own logic. I too can again put and give answers to your questions but it will become a debate

Comment: In Hadith 2# the Arabic and English  texts mismatch or are not properly quoted!

Answer (score 0):

> The Messenger of Allah (PBUH) said: "**When a person dies, all his actions come to an end except in respect of three matters which he leaves behind: a continuous charity: knowledge from which benefit could be derived; righteous offspring who pray for him.**" [Muslim & Ahmad]

First of all when you recite those Surahs you mentioned, understand their meanings while reciting.

Then when you understand them, you will find you're praising Allah by doing so, increasing the likeliness of him being pleased with you. After that when you(children) ask Allah for forgiveness on behalf of the deceased, probability of Allah listening to you(I mean forgiving them) increases. That's it.

As far as I know, there are no Hadith which talk about such a custom of reciting those Surahs and then making Dua for the deceased. This can be most probably attested to an evolved custom as explained above.

---

**Support:**

From here on I'll try to put some evidences towards and against the matter of contributing the thawab of reciting Surahs to the deceased (especially parents).

> Abdullah b. Buraida (Allah be pleased with him) reported on the authority of his father: When we were sitting with the Messenger of Allah (may peace be upon him), a woman came to him and said: I had gifted to my mother a maid-servant, and now she (the mother) has died. Thereupon he (the Holy Prophet) said: There is a definite reward for you and she (the maid-servant) has been returned to you as an inheritance. She (that woman) again said: Fasts of a month (of Ramadan) are due upon her; should I observe them on her behalf?He (the Holy Prophet) said: Observe fasts on her behalf. **She (again) said: She did not perform Hajj, should I perform it on her behalf? He (the Holy Prophet) said: Perform Hajj on her behalf.**

Hadith # 4 Taken from ali786's [answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/23634/11938).

The above bold part is our interesting part. In the first part of the Hadith, the woman asked permission from Prophet(pbuh) if she can perform those deeds on her mom's behalf, which her mom vowed/ought/desired/wished to perform when she was alive. The last thing is different (yes there are a couple of Hadith like this where the person asked prophet (pbuh) if he/she can perform deeds on their parents' behalf (nothing mentioned if their parents ought to do or not)).

I'm sorry, but there is a little disagreement in this regards among the scholars. We really don't know up to which extent the **bold** part is authentic (and also other such Hadith). **Assuming authentic**, then only those deeds which the people asked permission for are allowed to be done voluntarily, but not any other deeds like reciting Surahs.

Taking help of a critique's article [HOW CAN ONE MAN PAY FOR THE SINS OF ANOTHER?](http://www.answering-islam.org/Green/union.htm) (cuz he collected relevant Hadith for me), here is the summary of deeds which you can do voluntarily on the behalf of the deceased (by observing the Hadith we can infer that the deceased were mostly the parents),

1. Giving [Sadaqa](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/21717/is-it-a-good-idea-or-allowed-to-give-money-as-sadqah-when-i-dont-have-much) (charity).
2. Fasting.
3. Performing Hajj (scholars say that the children must have performed their part of Hajj prior at least once).

**Thats it.** I did not get a single Hadith directly in support of the topic asked in the Question.

---

Friendly tip, I understand you wish to benefit your parents, but although [reciting Qur'an has reward for each and every letter](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/23287/11938), I suggest you to prefer the prescribed methods/standards first (like the above). And if by any case, you could not go for the above methods, then try do as it seems good to you. But don't forget that Qur'an was sent to give guidance to the people during their test time. After the test time is over, the teacher just snatches away the paper, there is no use how much ever you wish to write in it. Make sure you utilize the guidance as much as you can in the 'action time'.

May the creator guide us all.

Comment: -1 ---He Asked the hadiths in the favour of this custom in bold font. Otherwise this question will become debate and need to close it.